# Ordering core data objects inside a table view section

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I am using NSSortDescriptors to order core data objects and create table view sections depending on a date attribute. Using this kind of SortDescriptor, the table view sections are ordered as expected, but the rows inside the sections are also ordered by the same date attribute. Is there a way to have another ordering system inside each section? I guess the main problem is that core data stores date objects with date+time values, that way there are no objects with exactly the same date value. But I would need to order the objects inside the same section based on another attribute.
Thank you.

And here is my code for the NSFetchedResultsController:

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultsController{

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil){
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"itemDate" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"itemName" ascending:NO];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortDescriptor,sortDescriptor1, nil];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptors;
    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionIdentifier" cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

EDITED QUESTION

This is the piece of code added to the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
int indexpathsection = indexPath.section;
    [self sortedSectionForIndex:indexpathsection];
    NSLog(@"INDEXPATH= %ld", (long)indexPath.section);
```

And this is the method proposed y Marcus:

```
- (NSArray*)sortedSectionForIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"priority" ascending:YES];
    id section = [[self fetchedResultsController] sections][index];
    NSLog(@"INDEX********* = %ld", (long)index);
    NSArray *objects = [section objects];
    NSArray *sorted = [objects sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];
    return sorted;
}
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! you'll get better answers if you show your data structure/code.

Comment: thank you, I will add my NSFetchedResultsController code to my question.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman,  I have added my code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NSFetchedResultsController` is meant for the sort order to be controlled via a single sort or set of sorts.  It is not intended to do what you are trying to do.

But you can do it, it is just not as clean.

First, the discussion of sorting a section. This does not require you to write your own sorting algorithm:

```
- (NSArray*)sortedSectionForIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"MyKey" ascending:YES];
    id section = [[self fetchedResultsController] sections][index];
    NSArray *objects = [section objects];
    NSArray *sorted = [objects sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];
    return sorted
}
```

With that method, you can ask for a section to be sorted whenever you want to retrieve an object.  However that is inefficient as you are sorting every time you want to touch an object which in a `UITableViewController` is a **LOT**.

Instead, take this example and integrate it with your `NSFetchedResultsController` and its delegate methods so that you are storing the sorted arrays and keeping them in sync.  That way you are only doing the sort when the data changes instead of on each method call.

### Update

The sort code I provided to you does not sort what is **inside** of the `NSFetchedResultsController`.  It takes what is in the section, sorts it and returns you the sorted array.  So you need to use what it returns:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSArray *sorted = [self sortedSectionForIndex:[indexPath section]];
    id object = [sorted objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    id cell = ...; //Now get your cell reference

    //Now update your cell with the data from object

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I think your answer should help me, but where to integrate it would be my next question. You say to integrate it with my NSFetchedResultsController and its delegate methods, but how, I know this is a complete method that returns an array, but I don't see from where should I call it... thank you for help

Comment: From anywhere that needs access to the data. `-cellForRowAtIndexPath...` might be a good place to start.

Comment: Marcus, when calling your method from the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, I guess I should do it as follows: [self sortedSectionForIndex:sectionIndex]; sectionIndex should be the section to be sorted.

Comment: Marcus, I have done it as follows: int indexPathSection = indexPath.section; [self sortedSectionForIndex:indexPathSection]; Inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. It doesn't sort for the attribute put in sortDescriptorWithkey.

Comment: Marcus, would you mind helping me with my previous comment? I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Post the code as you have written the changes so that I can review it.

Comment: Marcus, I have post the code to my question text. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Thank you for your updated answer. I think that your answer is not giving me a good solution for my problem, then I guess that the NSArray that has the ordered sections objects is in conflict with the rest of my project, then using your solution, other methods of my app are now crashing, like the search bar controller, etc. I will need another solution to my problem that makes use of the NSFetchedResultsController...

Comment: There is no solution that uses the `NSFetchedResultsController`.  It does not work that way.  For the solution I gave you, you need to always retrieve the objects after calling the sort. So, as I mentioned, you will need to put similar code in every place that you need to retrieve the objects in the sort order.

Comment: Thank you Markus, then I will need to change part of my app.

Answer (score 0):

You can normalize the time component of your attribute in the `awakeFromFetch`method of your `NSManagedObject`.

```
- (void) awakeFromFetch {
    [super awakeFromFetch];
    NSDateComponents* comps = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit  fromDate:self.itemDate];
    self.itemDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:comps];     
}
```

In addition, looking at your code, you have to tell the `NSFetchedResultsController` on what it should base the section breaks. You do this by providing a keyPath for the section breaks when you initialize it. For your case, instead of using `sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionIdentifier"`, use the first sort key:

```
    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:@"itemDate" cacheName:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you, but changing the sectionNameKeyPath as you propose is not working, the sections are not shown...

Comment: I added information on how you can normalize the time component of itemDate in your managed object.