# Core Data objects ordering inside a section

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

In a previous question, a user asked for a method to order core data objects inside a UITableView Section. I am in the same case, but I don't find the way to implement the proposed solution.

The proposed solution was to create the following method:

```
- (NSArray*)sortedSectionForIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"priority" ascending:YES];
    id section = [[self fetchedResultsController] sections][index];
    NSLog(@"INDEX********* = %ld", (long)index);
    NSArray *objects = [section objects];
    NSArray *sorted = [objects sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];
    return sorted;
}
```

But I don't know how to call this method inside my code in the way that the section objects would be ordered.
Thank you.

Comment: if you say about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414396/ordering-core-data-objects-inside-a-table-view-section, you have to call it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Perhaps you should describe what you are trying to achieve. - In many cases, you just need two (or more) sort descriptors. The first one sorts into sections, the remaining ones sort within the section.

Comment: @MartinR, I am creating a To-Do list app. I am using a transient attribute to distribute the core data objects into sections. The fetchedResultsController sort descriptors are sorting on a date value and a priority value. In the tableView, there are sections for Overdue, Today, Tomorrow, Upcoming,..., In the Today and Tomorrow sections, the objects do have the same date/time value, that means that the objects inside these both sections are sorted on the second sort descriptor (priority), which is what I need. But in the other sections, the objects are sorted only by date.

Comment: @MartinR, what I need inside the other sections is to only sort by the priority value.

Comment: @dimimpou, you are right, this is the question I was talking about.

Comment: @mvasco: But that sounds as if you could apply the solution from the linked question, and call it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, as imimpou said (and is also mentioned in the answer to the linked question). - The only alternative that I can think of is to use a *persistent* attribute for the sections. Then you can use this attribute in the first sort descriptor.

Comment: @MartinR, this is what I have done: I have added the sortedSectionForIndex in my tableViewController.m file, and then I have included the code lines: NSArray *sorted = [self sortedSectionForIndex:[indexPath section]];
    id object = [sorted objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath method,but the objects are not sorted by the 'priority' value.

Comment: @MartinR, I can't use this method to sort the objects inside the sections, doing this the app crashes if the user makes use of the search bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should implement separate fetchedResultsController(s) and sort descriptor for the section(s) you want sorted differently.  Take a look at the CompanyMenuTableViewController code in this sample app.  One of the sections uses it's own fetchedResultsController. You would use a similar approach to handle each section independently of other sections, with each section having its own fetchedResultsController if necessary.

Make sure you download the most recent version.

http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/